# pandas restart cumsum every time the value is zero

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

so I have a series, I want to cumsum, but start over every time I hit a 0, somthing like this:

|  | orig | wanted result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 1 | 6 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 | 3 |
| 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 13 | 1 | 2 |
| 14 | 1 | 3 |
| 15 | 1 | 4 |
| 16 | 1 | 5 |
| 17 | 1 | 6 |

any ideas? (pandas, pure python, other)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `df['orig'].eq(0).cumsum()` to generate groups starting on each 0, then [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get the increasing values:

```
df['result'] = df.groupby(df['orig'].eq(0).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

output:

```
    orig  wanted result  result
0      0              0       0
1      1              1       1
2      1              2       2
3      1              3       3
4      1              4       4
5      1              5       5
6      1              6       6
7      0              0       0
8      1              1       1
9      1              2       2
10     1              3       3
11     0              0       0
12     1              1       1
13     1              2       2
14     1              3       3
15     1              4       4
16     1              5       5
17     1              6       6
```

Intermediate:

```
df['orig'].eq(0).cumsum()

0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    2
11    3
12    3
13    3
14    3
15    3
16    3
17    3
Name: orig, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
condition = df.Orig.eq(0)
df['reset'] = condition.cumsum()
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.